# How to print list inside python print?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, debugging, variadic-functions

I am trying to build a variable number of arguments logger as follow. I would like to call it like:

`log( 1, "Index: ", request_index, ", ", section )`

```
def log(level, *msg) :

    global print_debug_lastTime
    currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().microsecond

    # You can access global variables without the global keyword.
    if g_debug_level & level != 0:

        print( "[DEBUG] " \
                + "%02d" % datetime.datetime.now().hour + ":" \
                + "%02d" % datetime.datetime.now().minute + ":" \
                + "%02d" % datetime.datetime.now().second + ":" \
                + str( currentTime ) \
                + "%7d " % ( currentTime - print_debug_lastTime ) \
                + for m in msg )
```

But I am having trouble to print the variable number of arguments. Initially I am trying to run this simple code on the interpreter:

```
>>> print( str( x ) for x in (0,1,2,3) )
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x6ffffe5e550>
```

I would like it to print `0123`, but it is printing it as may be seem.

Comment: That is because what is inside your print is a generator expression, so you can do this: `print(list(str( x ) for x in (0,1,2,3)))`.

Comment: Thanks! `print( "".join([str( x ) for x in (0,1,2,3)]) )` did it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose your for with "[]"

```
print(tuple([str( x ) for x in (0,1,2,3)]))
```

> output = ['0', '1', '2', '3']

convert to tuple if you want

```
print(tuple([str( x ) for x in (0,1,2,3)]))
```

> output = ('0', '1', '2', '3')

AND in your case you want to concatenate with other string 
you can use following and add in your log string,

> tuple(str( x ) for x in (0,1,2,3)).__str__()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(''.join(str(x) for x in [0, 1, 2, 3]))
# 0123
```

Comment: Brackets after `join` can be removed .